# Why MySQL LEFT JOIN produces NULL results?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have been working on an expense tracking system. I have three main tables: 'expenses', 'expense_reports', 'payments'.

I structured my database like this:

- 'expenses' belongs to one 'expense_reports'
- 'expense_reports' has many 'expenses'
- 'expense_reports' belongs to many 'payments'
- 'payments' belongs to many 'expense_reports'

I added a pivot table namely 'expense_report_payment' for 'expense_reports' and 'payments' tables to handle many-to-many relationships.
'expense_report_payment' table has the ff fields:

- id
- expense_report_id
- payment_id
- payment

This is my query to fetch the total sum of expenses and payments:

```
SELECT SUM(ex.`amount`) AS total_expenses, SUM(erp.`payment`) AS total_payment FROM `expenses` ex
JOIN `expense_reports` er ON er.`id` = ex.`expense_report_id`
LEFT JOIN `expense_report_payment` erp ON erp.`expense_report_id` = er.`id`
LEFT JOIN `payments` p ON p.`id` = erp.`payment_id`
WHERE ex.`deleted_at` IS NULL
AND er.`deleted_at` IS NULL
AND er.`rejected_at` IS NULL
AND er.`cancelled_at` IS NULL
AND p.`deleted_at` IS NULL
AND p.`cancelled_at` IS NULL
AND p.`received_at` IS NOT NULL
```

I used LEFT JOIN TO display the results for expenses even if there is NO payment yet. However, I got NULL results.

Comment: well....the `AND p.received_at IS NOT NULL` makes it so the `LEFT JOIN` with `payments` is actually an `INNER JOIN`, since that condition is in effect a *there needs to be a paymen*

Comment: oh sweet. it did provide what i want. but i need it if there is a payment tho. payment can only be considered if it was received to complete the transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the help. I managed to resolve the issue by JOINING 'expense_report_payment' and 'payments' table inside a LEFT JOIN.

```
SELECT 
  IFNULL(SUM(ex.`amount`), 0) AS total_expenses,
  IFNULL(SUM(erp.payment), 0) AS total_payment
FROM
  `expenses` ex 
  JOIN `expense_reports` er 
    ON er.`id` = ex.`expense_report_id` 
    AND er.`deleted_at` IS NULL 
    AND er.`rejected_at` IS NULL 
    AND er.`cancelled_at` IS NULL 
  LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
      ep.*
    FROM
      `expense_report_payment` ep 
      JOIN `payments` p 
        ON p.`id` = ep.`payment_id`
    WHERE p.`received_at` IS NOT NULL
    AND p.`deleted_at` IS NULL
    AND p.`cancelled_at` IS NULL
    ) AS erp 
    ON erp.expense_report_id = er.`id` 
WHERE ex.`deleted_at` IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You are requiring p.received_at to not be NULL, so there must always be a payment.

I question why you join payments at all; you are not using anything from that table, though as is you are restricting what you report to erps with payments with all those fields null.

I'm guessing you want to only join payments that have received_at set:

```
LEFT JOIN payments p ON p.id=erp.payment_id AND p.received_at IS NOT NULL
```

Or if you want to include when there is no payment or there is a received payment, but exclude where there is a non-received payment, leave the join unchanged and change the where condition to:

```
AND (p.id IS NULL or p.`received_at` IS NOT NULL)
```

It's possible you want some of your p.foo IS NULL conditions to be in the join ON clause as well.

Comment: Thank you, It doesn't return null values anymore if there are no payments yet. However, if there is a payment, total payment amount still displays even if it is not received yet.